# Using kafka with multiple inputs and single output?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-kafka

Would Kafka be necessary if you have multiple streams of information coming into a centralized node, but all of them need to be processed in Hadoop or Spark?  Because there is no need to filter the different types of information, it seems like Kafka's ability to handle messages seems redundant.

In other words, if you have want an At Most System, would multiple Producers to a single Consumer negate the need for Kafka?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka is usually used with Spark-Streaming applications.  The reason it is used with Spark-Streaming applications, is that it can guarantee no data-loss in the event the receiver goes down.  If the data is already in the hadoop cluster and you're running batch jobs with spark, there really isn't a need for kafka to interface with spark.

Comment: Would something like RabbitMQ make more sense to create a queue for clustering the data for processing or is there a specific tool used to organize the information for batch jobs?

Comment: One of the main differences between RabbitMQ, 0MQ, similar queue systems and Kafka, it's that Kafka is designed as a commit log and used as a queue. This means messages are kept stored for certain amount of time even if they are read from consumers. Messages are replicated and distributed to handle respectively loss and high load. Kafka is usually a good choice also for the number of different implementation in many languages that allow to connect different systems. So to answer you question, Kafka is not necessary if you don't have these requirements

Comment: @PinoSan is right.  Do you have a reason you would want to queue up data prior to working with it in Spark?  I can't maybe see a use case where you'd want to have another system feed the data to Spark, unless you were trying to simulate some sort of streaming application.